# Hidden attributes on data.table rows

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to add metainfo to each row within a data.table and also filter by such? And if so, how can I do it?

Let's say for simplicity that I have a data table with 2 columns, A and B, where B contains numeric data. I need to be able to mark (some, all, just one, etc.) rows as `FIX`, do math operations, joins and so on, and later mark them as `UNFIX` so that when performing such operations, results are not affected by the metainfo as might be the case if they were just another column instead of a hidden attribute.

Comment: I don't understand your argument for not making them proper columns. Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it more clear?

Comment: you can use a separate vector if you want. e.g. `fix.rows = c(T,F,F)` or `fix.rows = c(1, 17, 23)`. Then do data table operations using this: `dt[fix.rows, V1 := x]`. But I don't see anything that couln't also be achieved simply using an extra column

Comment: @MrFlick, For example, I have a set functions that perform join operations between 2 data tables using intersect, given that the column number may grow in the future:
sk = intersect(names(dt1), names(dt2))
sk = sk[ !sk %in% "VALUE"]
dt1[dt2, VALUE := VALUE + i.VALUE, on = sk]

Answer (score 0):

R supports attributes on all objects.  So you can assign attributes to your list although it may not be the best approach - creating and dropping a new column is likely the best solution.  I would note that if you preform any operations on your list you will lose the attributes unless you copy them to the new object.  Here is a simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3),
                 B = c(1, 2, 3))

attr(df, "isFixed") <- c("unfixed","unfixed","unfixed")

attributes(df)$isFixed

attributes(df)$isFixed[1] <- "fixed"

attributes(df)$isFixed
```